# Any way to render a dynamically added modal from api with routing in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-routing

working on a project for a hospital in which data on patients gets pulled from their api and gets loaded as cards on the page (will provide screenshots). When you click on a card more info of the patient gets pulled up as a modal. The goal here is for them to render when someone searches for it based on slug. Each endpoint from the api has a slug: [API Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgrF7.png)

for example if you go to localhost:3000/WebersWarriors (localhost:3000/${shirt.slug}) it will render that specific modal and if you click on a card it would append "WebersWarriors" to the end of the URL. Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated thank you!
[Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7xPj.png)

[When card gets clicked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m94jV.png)

Modal code being displayed dynamically:

```
    const TshirtItem = props => {
      const classes = useStyles();
      const { shirt } = props;
      const theme = useTheme();
      const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
      const matches = useMediaQuery(theme.breakpoints.down('sm'));

      const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpen(true);

        setTimeout(() => {
          handleClose();
        }, 30000);
      };

      const handleClose = () => {
        setOpen(false);
      };

      const handleDetail = content => (
        <Dialog
          fullScreen={matches}
          className={classes.dialog}
          open={open}
          TransitionComponent={Transition}
          keepMounted
          onClose={handleClose}
          aria-labelledby="alert-dialog-slide-title"
          aria-describedby="alert-dialog-slide-description"
        >
          <DialogContent>
            <Grid container>
              <Grid item>
                {shirt.ar_lens_card !== null ? (
                  <img
                    key={shirt.ar_lens_card.id}
                    src={shirt.ar_lens_card.url}
                    title={shirt.ar_lens_card.name}
                    alt={shirt.ar_lens_card.name}
                    className={classes.dialog_img}
                  />
                ) : null}
              </Grid>

              <Grid item container>
                <Grid item xs={2} container direction="column">
                  <Typography
                    className={classes.tshirt_number}
                    color="textSecondary"
                  >
                    #{shirt.Tshirt_Number}
                  </Typography>
                </Grid>
                <Grid item xs={10} container>
                  <Grid item xs>
                    <Typography className={classes.label}>Team</Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.team_name}>
                      {shirt.team_name}
                    </Typography>

                    <hr className={classes.hr} />

                    <Typography className={classes.patient_name}>
                      {shirt.patient_first_name}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography
                      color="textSecondary"
                      className={classes.patient_diagnosis}
                    >
                      {shirt.patient_diagnosis}
                    </Typography>
                    <Typography className={classes.patient_bio}>
                      {shirt.patient_bio}
                    </Typography>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>
                {matches ? (
                  <IconButton
                    edge="start"
                    color="inherit"
                    onClick={handleClose}
                    aria-label="close"
                    className={classes.arrowback_icon}
                  >
                    <ArrowBackIosIcon fontSize="large" />
                  </IconButton>
                ) : null}
              </Grid>
            </Grid>
          </DialogContent>
        </Dialog>
      );
```

Comment: Please post code here and not as images. It can be hard to follow, is unstable and Imgur is blocked on my current network.

Comment: @ChrisB. added the code for the modal that pops up when you click on the card. so my goal is to get the this modal to pop up whenever user navigates to "localhost:3000/{shirt.slug}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code will be pretty similar to the [React-router gallery example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/modal-gallery).

You just need to fetch your data in your list component and render the cards. In the demo below I've used Bulma for styling and [React-masonry-css](https://github.com/paulcollett/react-masonry-css) for creating the Masonry grid.

The demo can be found [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-list-fetched-from-api-react-uh1xk).

The important part of the demo is the `Cards` component with the following code:

```js
const Cards = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);
  const [isFetching, setFetchStatus] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUsers = async () => {
      try {
        const { data } = await axios.get(API_URL);
        setUsers(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error("failed", err);
      }

      setFetchStatus(false);
    };

    fetchUsers();
  }, []);

  const location = useLocation();
  const background = location.state && location.state.background;

  return isFetching ? (
    "loading..."
  ) : (
    <Fragment>
      <Switch location={background || location}>
        <Route path="/" component={() => <Home users={users} />} />
      </Switch>

      {background && (
        <Route
          path="/user/:id"
          component={() => <RouterModal users={users} />}
        />
      )}
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

It is like in the gallery example except the `useEffect` that fetches the data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ API.

`useEffect` hook with an empty array as a parameter is in a class-based component the life cycle method `componentDidMount` - so it's just called on the first render.

**Things you could improve in your final app:**

- Check caching of the fetched data
- Limit the rendered cards (e.g. show only 1000 cards and filter by letters)
- Add a search field with typeahead
- Change the query to slug (in the demo it's the id because there's no slug in the fake api data)
- Move the components into different files (kept everything in one file just for the demo)